# How to novint falcon works with unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, falcon, haptic-feedback

I wanna make nobint falcon works with unity3d.
I search many pages and found an opensource project falconunity.
But it does not works than my project does not progress now.
Plz help....

Comment: Please specify what you have tried already, what's working, what isn't, etc. to expect an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By simply researching **"novint falcon unity"** here are the first results:

- [an open source project on GitHub](https://github.com/kbogert/falconunity): the one you tried I guess.
- [a unity forum post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/novint-falcon.6494/) where someone wrote a C++ wrapper compiled into a DLL: I personally used this one and can tell it worked with very few adjustments.
- [a unity answer's question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30673/integrating-the-novint-falcon-device-into-a-unity3.html) that links to the H3DAPI.

Using the wrapper you can find on the second link you can easily integrate the Novint Falcon into your project.

I remember you have to copy the number located on the back of the Falcon somewhere in a config file to have it work properly (otherwise it won't even connect).
Also if you want to use more than 1 Falcon, the trick we used was to connect/disconnect each of them one after another.

*Hope this helps,*